# indexing two varchar columns for query with String concatenation

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

I have two varchar columns A and B in postgres table with more than 1 000 000 rows. I want to make query with String concatenation SELECT * from table WHERE A||B like 'string%' . How do I make an index that would speed up this query ? I try to make separate indexes or index for both columns, but i does not work for query.

Comment: Can`t you adjust the search string rather than the column(s) so as to use only one column?What kind of data do you have?

Comment: I know, that the best is avoid such query, but I did not invite this query, this is someone else query :-( .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should help:

```
create index on the_table ((a||b) varchar_pattern_ops);
```

Note the `varchar_pattern_ops` parameter. This is needed in order to make the index usable for a `LIKE` query.

Your query must use **exactly** the same expression ( `a||b` ) as used in the index, otherwise it will never be used. The condition must be selective enough as well to warrant the index usage. If your query is going to return a substantial percentage of the rows in the table, using the index might not make sense. If your condition only returns a few thousand rows, it might be used by the optimizer.

Don't forget to run `analyze` after creating the index.

Comment: thanx a lot, with this index it works . Without index postgres was making Seq Scan on table with great costs. After creating the index the query is made using Bitmap Heap Scan. The costs are only one third of the costs without index. Very good.